# Don't get all href

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

Here is my web crawler class:

```
public class WebCrawler {

    private HashSet<String> visitedUrls;

    public WebCrawler() {
        visitedUrls = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    public void crawl(String url) throws IOException {
        // Check if URL is already visited
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Set<String> links = new HashSet<String>();
        URL urlObject = new URL(url);
        String domainName = urlObject.getHost();
        Elements elements = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element e : elements) {
            String l = e.attr("href");
            if(l.endsWith(".html")){
                if(!l.startsWith("http")){
                    l = domainName + l;
                    // Determine whether the URL is HTTP or HTTPS
                    if (urlObject.getProtocol().equals("https")) {
                       l = "https:/" + l;
                    } else if (urlObject.getProtocol().equals("http")) {
                            l = "http:/" + l;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The URL is neither HTTP nor HTTPS.");
                    }
                    links.add(l);
                    System.out.println(l);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        WebCrawler crawler = new WebCrawler();
        String url = "...";  // <- replace a URL
        crawler.crawl(url);
    }
}
```

I attempted to test the code on [a Yahoo page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PRVB/news?p=PRVB) to retrieve all linked pages on the page. However, the code only retrieves the first four links ending with ".HTML" and fails to capture all the links present on the page. Despite conducting online research on the issue, I am unable to determine the root cause of the problem. What could be the missing piece?

Comment: You have this in your code: `l.endsWith(".html")`. Did you write this or copy it and don't understand your own code?

Comment: I need linked pages, but not others such as images. That is a filter for the purpose. I see way more links on the page with .HTML at the end.

Comment: can you do some step through debugging to find out where your loop decides to exit?

Comment: I already tried to find the cause with the debug mode on IDEA. It took too long.